# Pop out a shape out of another shape

Tags: after-effects, visual-effects, shape

How do I do a 'pop out' effect from one shape out of the other?

Right now I have this:

[image: 11 no pop out]

But I would like if the shape visually appeared out of the left 1.  So like it stretches and then comes bursting loose. I don't know the right terms for this, so looking for a solution hasn't been easy.

How do I achieve this effect, and what is it called?
Thanks!

Comment: It's a little unclear what exactly you want to happen, which I think is the source of your problem. If you can work out exactly what you want to see that's most of the job done.

Comment: I feel like I kind of understand. But in any case i can't explain how to do it, it's sort of trial and error with scale and position key frames and apply a bounce expression maybe

Answer (score 1):

- For simple shape and best result you can do it frame by frame, drawing each morph state separately
- For more complex shapes, I will advise:

  1. Move second object (and maybe scale it from little size to normal) from behind first one
  2. Bend part of first object outwards slowly, while new object appear (simultaneously with point 1)
  3. In the moment, when second object is fully separated from first, first object shall rubber bend back with bash, as cartoon character, who was hit with the bat in the head, or as water surface, after water drop hit it.

To fully understand, what I mean in last point, look at this: